# c# - Run on another thread

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a function that causes the GUI to freeze while its running so am trying to get it to run on another thread, then update text once its complete.

I have it running on another thread fine, but not sure how to get it to update the text.

The working code

```
Task.Run(() =>{ emailHelper.sendEmail(name); });
```

I've tried modifying the code to

```
Task.Run(() => { errorMessage.Text = emailHelper.sendEmail(name); });
```

but get an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

How do I tell the application to update the GUI?

Comment: Store result in local variable. Then you can either invoke the setting of control text from within task (not sure how it's done in winui-3) or await for task to finish and set control text from outside the task.

Comment: sounds like an architecture issue - your server side code is still waiting for the thread to complete, before returning to client?  we solve this by invoking the operation - fire and almost forget - the server either returns a reference to the client - and it does long poll for status, or use a web socket, on completion server notifies client of outcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Task can also *return* values, as well.
you can then assign that value to your GUI element.

```
var message = await Task.Run(() => { 
  return emailHelper.sendEmail(name); 
});
errorMessage.Text = message;
```

Or shorter:

```
errorMessage.Text = await Task.Run(() => emailHelper.sendEmail(name));
```

Comment: That results in  - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

Comment: @CeriTurner Is `sendEmail` already async?

Comment: did you include the `await`-call? that part is important. or, if `sendEmail` already returns a task, there's no need to wrap it in `Task.Run` in the first place (and your original code wouldn't even have compiled)

Comment: Send email just returns a string. If i include the await, it doesn't compile - The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: It might be helpful to note that simple lambdas like this can be written as an expression, i.e.  `() => 
  emailHelper.sendEmail(name)`

Comment: @Ceri Turner you need to mark the method as [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)